# WF ThrowActivities and custom error messages?

Tags: workflow-foundation

is it possible to throw a custom error message to a ThrowActivity, in windows workflow foundation?

eg. Imagine i want to throw this exception, in my WF :-

```
CutomException("This is my custom error message", myNumber, myObect);
```

cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I do not understand your question well, but you can set the specific exception with the `Fault` property of `ThrowActivity` in any place before the activity execution, e.g.:

```
throwActivity1.Fault = new CustomException("This is my custom error message", myNumber, myObect);
```

Comment: Yep! Perfect! i couldn't figure out how to do that in the designer .. so i did it in the code behind .. works great. Checking the designer again, it still makes no sence :P but that's ok :)

Answer (score 1):

You can throw any custom exception like this way.

public DiscontinuedProductException discontinuedProductException1 = new DiscontinuedProductException();

[SerializableAttribute()]
    public class DiscontinuedProductException : Exception
    {
        public DiscontinuedProductException()
            : base()
        {
        }

```
    public DiscontinuedProductException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public DiscontinuedProductException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }

    protected DiscontinuedProductException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
    }
}
```